# Cleaning up variables in methods

Tags: c#

I am having some memory issues in a large piece of software I work on, I am looking through methods we have written where we are declaring variables at the beginning of the method, but they are not being cleaned (nullified or disposed) at the end of the method.

```
public static bool CheckIsNumber(string x)
{
    int y;
    return(int.TryParse(x, out y));
}
```

as you see above, `y` is never set to null or disposed or anything like that, I always thought it would be picked up by the GC, but after looking through a memory profiler, I am not so sure anymore.

Comment: It's a static method, which implies (to me) that it will last for the life of the application, and won't be GC'd like an instance method or variable would.  I could be waaaaaaaaayyyyyyyy wrong though.

Comment: This is a local variable, it goes out of scope when the method returns. This is not a problem.

Comment: They'll be picked up by the garbage collector, but when that happens is non-deterministic.  Even though the method is static,  the scope of `y` is that method, and as soon as the method completes, the GC knows it can pick those up.

Comment: If the variable holds something that needs to be disposed, you should dispose of it when done with it. Int32 is not such something however.

Comment: I was pretty sure as soon as the method ended it would cleanup after itself, but i just wanted to make sure, guess my leak is somewhere else!

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen, what about a byte array? (byte[]) we use 3 different arrays in our encrypt / decrypt methods and those are used *alot*, like they are called every 10 - 15 seconds./.

Comment: Same thing. The GC takes care of it. If you have an actual memory leak (which is unlikely), then this isn't it.

Comment: @pep: so why did you tell him if you know it's not a good idea???

Comment: `int y` is very strange example of creating "garbage". And it is somewhat hard to assign `null` to `int` or dispose it. Please consider more realistic sample for your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a distinction between a variable going out of scope and garbage collection in .NET.  Microsoft lists three conditions that will trigger garbage collection:

1. The system has low physical memory.
2. The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap surpasses an acceptable threshold.
3. The GC.Collect method is called.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx#conditions_for_a_garbage_collection

When I've looked at memory usage of my .NET apps, they generally rise steadily to a certain point after which the Garbage Collector collects and the memory usage drops again.  The best I can tell that's exactly how it's meant to work.